# In App Purchase - Endless Loop

Tags: ios, swift, transactions, in-app-purchase

I'm getting the "endless loop" problem with IAPs. I did already research on quite a few topics regarding this problem, but it seems, it's different in my case.
Problem: Getting prompts to sign in to iTunes account when launching the app and also while using phone normally these pop ups appear.
Prompts appearing for my testbox users and personal iTunes account.

**Information:**

- **First assumption**: Transaction not finished
- I **DIDN'T** delete the sandbox testers, so I tried finishing the transaction with signing in to iTunes. *Which didn't resolve the issue.*
- Then I tried manually resolving the left over Transactions in AppDelegate but `SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions` is returning 0 objects.
- As stated in the Apple Docs, the Observer's delegate function should be called after app launch but `updatedTransaction` doesn't gets called. (I implemented the `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(my_observer)` in AppDelegate)
- Testing according to Apple Docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW12) worked fine but i ran into problems at 4: Test an interrupted transaction
  But as I tested this case yesterday for the first time and the issues already occured before this test, I wouldn't directly associate it with the main cause of my problem.

**Additional Information:**

- I tried two different approaches: 1: Setting up everything in the PurchaseVC and 2: Singleton (PurchaseManager class). 
  So implementation most certainly is correct for IAPs since I followed 2 different tutorials and compared the code to Apple's IAP best practices.

Best regards, 
Max

Comment: You say those prompts come even when outside of your application. Do they continue if you delete the app from the phone? Also what happens when you sign in to the itunes account?

Comment: Yes even outside. I deleted it one hour ago and since then no promts.

Comment: And you say you finish all transactions for each transactionState not just for .purchased. regardless of state all transactions have to be finished at the end or retried. Just trying to guess what might have gone wrong.

Comment: I finish transaction for .purchased, .restored, .failed.  For .purchasing and .deferred i do not.